# Dragging a 3D shape onto a Google Map?

Tags: google-maps, 3d, drag-and-drop, draggable

I want to allow a user to drag a 3D shape onto a Google Map. Imagine a map, zoomed into a neighborhood in satellite view, and the user would be able to drag a shape (simulating a building) onto that map and get a sense of the impact of that building in that neighborhood. I have not found any examples of this online.

Answer (score 0):

Why 3D? If you want to do this at "Street View" level, then this is much, much bigger in scope than a StackOverflow question -- it is basically a research project.

I would start by Googling the following terms:

1. relighting
2. re rendering
3. reprojection
4. proxy geometry

If it's a 2D map, then it's fairly easy to do and I'm not sure which part you need help with.

Comment: Thank you! A little more research on my part might point me toward sticking SketchUp models on Google Earth. Thanks again.